# URL search query alternatives

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, url

On the website I'm making, there are several tables on different pages, and each table has a bunch of different data entries. There's a search functionality on all pages: the user can search for text, and if one of the entries on the current page contains that text, it is displayed. However if the text is found in a data entry on another page, the user will be redirected to that page where they'll see the entry they're looking for.

The problem is passing the search query from the first page to the second. So far I've been doing this through the URL, something like this:

```
https://somewebsite.com/page1?q=searchQuery
```

This approach is a little problematic, because clearing the query isn't possible until you navigate to another page or erase it manually. The most intuitive approach to quickly clear the search box is to refresh (for some users, including me), but that obviously doesn't work here; the query will still be in the URL.

The only alternative I could think of is [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), but it's not well supported by older versions of IE.

Is there any other good alternatives?

Comment: It reloads the page though.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. I need the search query to show up in the search box after the redirection, but to clear __if__ the user decides to reload, which doesn't work with the URL search query. So i'm trying to avoid it altogether. Your suggestion only makes sense if I could somehow handle the event of a user refreshing the page, and execute `location.replace(".")` before the reload.

Comment: Your question isn't clear then.  I read you saying that refreshing the page is what you want, but it doesn't clear the querystring.  I'll delete my comments - I suggest you read how to create a [MCVE]